# jQuery MySQL date to h:m:s time back

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have this format in my database:

`2014-01-08 00:00:00`

How can I convert that format to jQuery / JavaScript so it shows how many hours, minutes and seconds there is back before it ends?

Comment: do you mean countdown? if yes try https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr&ei=O0LSUt3_B6utiQeXrYCIDQ#q=javascript+timer+countdown

Answer (score 2):

That format is directly parseable in recent browsers

JS:

```
Date.parse("2014-01-08 00:00:00")
```

so you wouldn't need conversion.

Cheers